# Реализация класса для парсинга на Selenium

Tags: python, ооп, парсер, selenium

Хочу реализовать класс для взаимодействия с Selenium, для парсинга.
Суть такова - есть сайт с которого поступает запрос на проверку чека, когда поступает запрос мы должны спарсить данные с сайта и отдать программе.
Так вот, как лучше реализовать создание драйвера ? Запихнуть в инициализацию или сделать это прямо в классе?

```
class BillChecker:
    URL = ""
    CDM = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    ua = UserAgent()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
    options.add_argument(f"--user-agent='{ua.random}'")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(CDM), options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()

    stealth(driver,
            languages=["en-US", "en"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )


    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
```

либо

```
class BillChecker:
    URL = ""
    CDM = ChromeDriverManager().install()

    def __init__(self, ...):
         ...
         ua = UserAgent()
         options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

         options.add_argument('--headless')
         options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
         options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
         options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
         options.add_argument(f"--user-agent='{ua.random}'")
         options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
         options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
         options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
         options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
         options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

         driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(CDM), options=options)
         driver.maximize_window()

         stealth(driver,
                 languages=["en-US", "en"],
                 vendor="Google Inc.",
                 platform="Win32",
                 webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
                 renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
                 fix_hairline=True,
                 )
```

Может вообще стоит изменить реализацию..?

Comment: В последней версии `Selenium` `ChromeDriverManager().install()` не нужен. https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/